# How to make RESTEasy understand static resource?

Tags: java, spring, rest, web, resteasy

My legacy system was implemented by RESTEasy with root mapping `/*`

Now I want to add some static resources such as images, html and I can not access these resources. The **RESTEasy servlet** says something like this

**`Could not find resource for relative : /WEB-INF/jsp/healthcheck/healthcheck.jsp`**

Is there anyway to configure RESTEasy to understand static resource in my case just like **`<mvc:resources>`** in Spring

Answer (score 0):

To serve static resources, you need to use the filter dispatcher instead if the servlet dispatcher.

This is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.7.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#filter):

> The downside of running Resteasy as a Servlet is that you cannot have
>   static resources like .html and .jpeg files in the same path as your
>   JAX-RS services. Resteasy allows you to run as a Filter instead. If a
>   JAX-RS resource is not found under the URL requested, Resteasy will
>   delegate back to the base servlet container to resolve URLs.